# Setting up CEDET/EDE to work with Irrlicht

Tags: c++, emacs, cedet, irrlicht

I have CEDET 1.0pre7 set up with emacs 23.1, and I want to use it to manage irrlicht programs. I am pretty new at writing non-academic C++ code, and makefiles. I got the following makefile to work for me:

```
game.exe: game.o
    g++ game.o -o game.exe -L "D:/irrlicht/irrlicht-1.7.1/lib/Win32-gcc/" -l Irrlicht
game.o: game.cpp
    g++ -c game.cpp -o game.o -I"D:/irrlicht/irrlicht-1.7.1/include"
```

How do I set up CEDET so that it will make this for me? I do not know how to add in libraries, and adding the irrlicht include path to system-include has done nothing.

Comment: Maybe you could look into the CEDET core, EDE, http://cedet.sourceforge.net/projects.shtml?

Comment: I've looked through the EDE documentation a number of times, but I could not figure out how to add a library.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Make or Automake project that is automatically generating your Makefiles, the process to modify features such as additional libraries to use is with the customize interface.  In a buffer (game.cpp) do this:

```
M-x customize-target RET
```

then go down to where it says this:

```
Ldlibs :
[INS]
Libraries, such as "m" or "Xt" which this program depends on. [More]
```

and middle-click INS to add an entry slot, then type in your library name.  If you haven't used the customize interface in Emacs before, it could be a little tricky to get used to.  Middle click activates buttons, and the interface is for editing structures, so think of lists when you click INS (insert) and DEL (delete) for different slots.